How to add items one by one from a checkbox group to an array in Typescript React
I want to add items to an array one by one when checkboxes are ticked one by one. I have tried the following code by spreading the value but it always rewrites the previous value with the value from the next checkbox.
const [items, setItems] = useState<any>([])
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

const handleSelectable = () => {
        if(!checked){
            setChecked(true)
            let new_items = {id:props.id, name:props.title}
            setItems(items.push(...items, new_items))
            
            console.log(items)
        
        }else{
            setChecked(false)
        }
    }


It seems like the issue in your code lies in how you're updating the state of the items array. Instead of directly pushing the new item into the items array, you should create a new array with the previous items along with the new item.
const [items, setItems] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

const handleSelectable = () => {
    if (!checked) {
        setChecked(true);
        const new_item = { id: props.id, name: props.title };
        setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, new_item]);
        console.log(items);
    } else {
        setChecked(false);
    }
};


Hello, I gave this code a try but its returning an empty array when I console log it
const new_item = { id: props.id, name: props.title };         setItems((prevItems:any) => [...prevItems, new_item]);

Try consoling items . Since this is where you need the updated array. Let me know about  the result.

Yeah, that was what I did above, I logged items and it returned an empty array. I shoud've included that line in the above comment to be more clear, my bad

I think there is something else wrong with your code . Here is another article for your reference link.

I tried this as well, No luck :/
